# VS 2019 - C Compiler: strange behavior

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c99

I have the following small C-programm (main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("bmi %.1f \n", bmi(85, 1.5f));
    return 0;
}

float bmi(int weight, float height) {
    return weight / (height * height);
}
```

1. Why does it compile without error? I expected that I need a prototype of the bmi()-function before the main().
2. When I debug the program, height is 0.0 not 1.5! What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it compile without error?

The C language used to allow implicit declarations prior to the C99 standard, and VS defaults to that behavior. However, with the default settings, VS *does* issue the following warnings, which should not be ignored.

```
(4,30): warning C4013: 'bmi' undefined; assuming extern returning int
(4,12): warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%.1f' requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int'
```

You can promote `C4013` to an error ([`/we"4013"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-160)) in which case the compilation will actually fail instead of issuing just a warning. In recent versions 16.8 and later compiling with [`/std:c11`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160) should disable implicit declarations and always trigger an error (disclaimer: not tried).

> When I debug the program, height is 0.0 not 1.5! What's going on?

At the point the compiler sees the `bmi(85, 1.5f)` call, it will assume the implicit function declaration `int bmi()`. In particular, it will assume the return value is an `int` so it will pass it as an `int` to `printf`. But the format string `"%.1f"` tells `printf` to expect a `double` argument (following the default promotion rules), so what happens next is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).